# Slow HttpResponse content retrieving with nginx on android

Tags: android, nginx, httprequest

I have a problem with retrieving data from a http request.
With some server requests, it takes a minute to parse the content from the server.
The data in the request is a short json message (stored in the answer string), so it doesn't have to take so long.

I'm using the org.apache libraries in android

This only happens with our nginx server in production, not with my development webrick server (yes it's a rails api)

This code is used in a super class used for all our api intents, but it's only slow in some occasions (some api requests)

The code hangs on the toString method on the third line

```
HttpResponse result = ... ;
HttpEntity response = result.getEntity();
String answer = EntityUtils.toString(response);
```

Is this a common problem?

EDIT:
These are the wireshark logs
https://img.skitch.com/20120426-jddnkdbhuttfujym9u4m7a2ph1.jpg

Comment: If you do multithreaded requests you could be hitting the connection limit (2 per host by default) and block yourself

Comment: this is the only request at that moment

Comment: Wireshark log has a 65 second delay before the server answers. I would interpret that as server problem, nothing in your Android code / device related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, problem solved

It was a server issue after all,
In the rails code, don't forget to add your status code

We had:

```
respond_with({:auth_token => current_user.authentication_token}, :location => nil)
```

This fixed it:

```
respond_with({:auth_token => current_user.authentication_token},:status => :ok, :location => nil)
```